# I can't convert my Text-To-Speech in Python 3.11

Tags: python, pytorch, gtts

When i run my program it gives me error in this code

```
import os

from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf


def speaker_gtts(text):
    lang = os.getenv('LANG')
    with BytesIO() as f:
        gTTS(text=text, lang=lang, slow=False).write_to_fp(f)
        f.seek(0)
        data, fs = sf.read(f)
        sd.play(data, fs, blocking=True)


models_urls = ['https://models.silero.ai/models/tts/en/v3_en.pt',
               'https://models.silero.ai/models/tts/ru/v3_1_ru.pt']

model_ru = 'silero_models/ru/model.pt'
model_en = 'silero_models/en/model.pt'

device = torch.device('cpu')
torch.set_num_threads(4)
local_file = model_ru

if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
    torch.hub.download_url_to_file(models_urls[0],
                                   local_file)  

model = torch.package.PackageImporter(local_file).load_pickle("tts_models", "model")
model.to(device)

sample_rate = 48000
speaker='kseniya'   #aidar, baya, kseniya, xenia, eugene
en_speaker = 'en_6' # от 0 до 117


def speaker_silero(text):
    audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                                speaker=speaker,
                                sample_rate=sample_rate)

    sd.play(audio, blocking=True)
```

And then it gives error in console

```
line 29, in speaker_silero
    audio = model.apply_tts(text=text, speaker=speaker, sample_rate=sample_rate)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<torch_package_0>.multi_acc_v3_package.py", line 303, in apply_tts
AssertionError: `speaker` should be in en_0, en_1, en_2, en_3, en_4, en_5, en_6, en_7, en_8, en_9, en_10, en_11....en_117
```

I tried changing speaker and did some research online but it didn't work for me
I am using PyCharm
Python 3.11
i also tried it on 3.8 and 3.12 but didn't work